# SQLite vs JSON for data retrieval in React Native

Tags: react-native, sqlite

Which is more efficient for data retrieval in React Native?

1. Storing a JSON file with approximately 2500 entries, and loading the JSON file and retrieving specific entries by their index.
2. Having an SQLite db on the client and storing the same entries and retrieving them by index.

Does the SQLite db have any advantage when comes to speed of loading and efficiency here? Or is using JSON equivalent?

Comment: Did you make measurements and comparisons?